# How to position a button on a scrolled container in flutter

Tags: flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have several windows that are jpg images of various sizes.
For the small ones, I can simply position a "FloatingActionButton" using screen coordinates:

```
        Positioned(
        height: 150,
        width: 150,
        top: 540,
        left: 860,
```

How can I position them on large jpg images, where I have to scroll ("SingleChildScrollView") further down the jpg? Increasing the "top" value above the maximum screen coordinate does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I broke up the large scrolled image into a series of small "containers."
It isn't a very elegant solution, but it works.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [

              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Image.asset('images/Wunderkinder_Tablet_2.png',
                          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              Image.asset('images/Wunderkinder_Tablet_4a.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),

              Stack(
                children:[
                  Image.asset('images/Wunderkinder_Tablet_4t.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
                  Row(

                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [

                      SizedBox(
                        width: 210,
                        height: 161,
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          heroTag: "btn5",
                          elevation: 0,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0),
                          shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => sp4artifakt1()),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),

                      SizedBox(
                        width: 210,
                        height: 161,
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          heroTag: "btn1",
                          elevation: 0,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0),
                          shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => sp4spiel1()),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).